# Refresh LoginPartial.cshtml view at will

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a login partial class in my MVC5 application. I want to change its view when I change a value in the viewbag.

When `viewbag.userlogged = "yes"` show logout, and vice versa.

ie. It should become logout when I login / it should become login when I logout.

With what I have, the homepage is doing exactly that however my other pages aren't refreshing.

How can I repaint the `loginpartial` whenever I want to?

Comment: Resolved: by setting the value of viewbag to logged in or logged out in every controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  Logout
}
else 
{
   Login
}
```